# How to run jar with JOGL app without -D key?

Tags: java, jar, jogl

I tried top learn Java because it's the easiest way to make cross platform apps(python too but I've already know it). I tried to write hello world program with JOGL. I've written it and it runs perfectly in my Eclipse and NetBeans but when I'm trying to build jar and run it it says that there isn't JOGl in the java.library.path. I tried to pass library path with -D argument and it works!
**The question**: Is there is a way to run it without any additional args? With only double click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a manifest file in your project: `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (probably you already have it in your project tree).
And There you can specify your classpath, for example:

```
Class-Path: lib/jogl.jar lib/other_lib.jar
```

Then make sure that this file goes in your jar. For more information http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html

Comment: Tried this:
Manifest-Version: 1.0 \
Created-By: HiTECNOLOGYs \
Main-Class: game.ProjectEvolve \
Class-Path: lib/jogl.jar lib/gluegen-rt.jar lib/jinput.jar lib/joal.jar \

Don't work, says: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path'.
WTF?

Comment: So I don't know, jogl is a bit tricky because it have native libraries. If you only want to run it with a double click you always can do a .bat/.sh script with your `java -D ...` command

Comment: JOGL is not tricky, any Java binding of OpenGL requires some native code to access to OpenGL. However, in JOGL 2.0, you only need to put jogl.all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar into the class path and to put the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directories. Then, JOGL 2.0 automatically loads them without any need of setting the Java library path.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes time to deploy to users, deploy the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  That makes using natives a 'one click' install for the end-user, and it can also partition the native download between platforms.

> Is there is a way to run it without any additional args? With only double click.

JWS also offers desktop integration - desktop shortcuts and menu items with icons, on the supported OS'.

Comment: Good answer. The "fat JAR" approach has tons of limitations. Java Webstart is a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the above very easily using a tool like [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice). Just follow the gui, its pretty easy to do. The application will put the natives inside the jar for you, so all you have to do is double click the jar to run your jogl application.

Comment: JarSplice is officially supported by JogAmp APIs since January 2014, it wasn't the case when you posted your answer (September 2011).

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Java library path is no more required in JOGL 2.0. You just need to set the class path (jogl-all.jar and gluegen-rt.jar must be in the class path) and to put the JARs containing the native libraries into the same directories whatever you use (applications, applets, Java Web Start, etc...). Then, JOGL 2.0 automatically loads the native libraries.